# Is the Force wielded to fire the Death Star's weapon?

Tags: star-wars, kyber-crystal

Kyber crystals are used to create lightsabers and also the Death Star's massive energy weapon.

A Jedi must use the Force to wield a lightsaber.  **Is the Dark Side of the Force used to fire the Death Star's energy weapon? If not, how is it made to fire?**

I vaguely recall that Darth Vader was in a detached role with respect to the energy weapon. I do not recall what either Darth Vader or the Emporer were doing when the weapon was being fired.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Darth Vader wasn't present on the Death Star during either of its firings in *Rogue One*, and specifically describes the Death Star's power as "insignificant next to the power of the Force" in *A New Hope*, so it seems safe to say that he wasn't involved in its ignition.

As to using the Force to wield a lightsaber, we know from the films that you don't need to be a Force-user to *turn on* a lightsaber:

[image: Han Solo using Luke's lightsaber]

So, it stands to reason that you don't need to use the Force to activate a kyber crystal in general.

As to how it *is* fired, the *Rogue One Ultimate Visual Guide* has this to say:

> The size of a small moon, it is a mobile, planet-killing superweapon, able to transform and focus the raw energy of hypermatter reactions at its heart into a world-shattering superlaser. This energy transformation, using Galen Erso's kyber crystal formulae, was the most difficult technical hurdle to overcome.
>
> [...]
>
> The Death Star superlaser focuses eight tributary laser streams into an amplification nexus to create a blast magnified through kyber crystal field dynamics.

That is, it's some kind of interaction between lasers and kyber crystals. If it's Force-related, neither the guide or *Star Wars: Catalyst* say so.